# Covariance Matrix and Gaussian Process

Tags: machine-learning, probability, stochastic-processes, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process

In a paper i'm reading they use gaussian processes but i'm a little bit confused about their use of the covariance matrix. The setup is as follows: the inputs are $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^Q$ and there are $N$ of them. They are stored in a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times Q}$. The outputs are D dimensional and are stored in a matrix $\mathbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times D}$.

Then they assume the following model:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{F} | \mathbf{X} & \sim \mathcal{N}({\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{K}(\mathbf{X,X}})) \\
\mathbf{Y} | \mathbf{F} & \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{F}, \tau \mathbf{I}_N)
\end{align*}

where $\mathbf{K(X,X)}$ is $N \times N$ matrix and $\mathbf{I}_N$ matrix. This is the part i don't understand, how can the covariance matrix be of size $N \times N$ when the observations are D dimensional. Same for the function values $\mathbf{F}$, they are D dimensional yet the covariance matrix is $N \times N$. If it is the case, how do i sample from $\mathbf{Y} | \mathbf{F}$?

Comment: Could you post the link to the paper for the reference?

Comment: here, page 3: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v48/gal16-supp.pdf

Comment: It seems to me that what is meant by this is: to sample F, for each q = 1,...,Q sample a gaussian around 0 with cov $K(X,X)$, which will yield a NxQ matrix. Then to sample Y, for each column of F (a N vector), sample a gaussian around it with cov $\tau I_N$ and concatenate the D samples. This seems to be consistent with the assumption 'as the output dimensions of a multi-output Gaussian process are assumed to be independent.' in page 4.